# Unit-testing a Flux.take(Duration duration) with StepVerifier

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, project-reactor

I am using Spring Reactor Core 3.0.6 and I have a method returning a Flux:

```
public Flux<Foo> createFlux(){
    return Flux.<List<Foo>,String>generate(/* generator omitted for clarity's sake */ )
        .take(Duration.ofSeconds(10)
        .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);
}
```

The generator function calls a paginated REST api to get the results, and if the API continue to return data, I want the Flux to just run for 10 seconds.

It works fine, but I'd like to create some unit-testing and I have trouble in creating a test to verify that the Flux run only for 10 seconds at maximum.

I mocked the rest service so that it always return data and wrote this:

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> createFlux())
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .verifyComplete();
```

but it fails:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expectation "expectComplete" failed (expected: onComplete(); actual: onNext([my toString() Foo bean]))
```

I guess that I should consume the generated items in some way, but I am unable to find the right StepVerifier method to do so.

**EDIT**

I try to skip every items with `thenConsumeWhile`:

```
StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> createFlux())
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .thenConsumeWhile(t -> true)
    .verifyComplete();
```

but now the test just runs indefinitely and never ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator might in fact be very important... `StepVerifier` is limited with infinite sequences, even more so when using virtual time. The problem is that both the generator and the `thenAwait` run in the main thread, so the generator being infinite prevents the stepverifier from advancing time, which in turn prevents the sequence to time out.

Since you want to test the duration of the `take`, I don't think virtual time is right (you're testing a mock of time). I'd make the createFlux method parameterizable with the take duration, and do a `StepVerifier.create()`, for a much shorter duration.

If you really want to use some form of virtual time, I found that the minimal requirement to make it work is to

1. Isolate the generator loop on a **non virtual** thread by instantiating the `Scheduler` at the beginning of the test, then use `subscribeOn(scheduler)` in the StepVerifier's `Supplier`.
2. Ensure everything is subscribed and data starts to flow before attempting to advance time, by calling `.expectNextCount(1)` first.

Like this:

```
public Flux<Integer> createFlux() {
    return Flux.<List<Integer>>generate(sink -> {
        sink.next(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    })
            .take(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .flatMap(Flux::fromIterable);
}

@Test
public void so44657525() throws InterruptedException {
    Scheduler scheduler = Schedulers.newSingle("test");
    AtomicInteger adder = new AtomicInteger();

    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> createFlux()
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
            .doOnNext(v -> adder.incrementAndGet())
    )
                .expectNextCount(1)
                .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
                .thenConsumeWhile(t -> true)
                .verifyComplete();

    System.out.println("Total number of values in generated lists: " + adder.get());
}
```

Modifying the `expectNextCount(1)` to `expectNextCount(100_000)`, I had a run that printed `Total number of values in generated lists: 102405` and took 40ms.

Comment: thanks, it indeed worked. I made just a single change: instead of `.verifyComplete()` I use `.expectComplete().verify(Duration.ofSeconds(10L))`. This way, if the flux runs for more than 10 seconds, it will throw an assertion error. With verifyComplete it runs indefinitely. If the flux runs for the expected 10s, both solutions are fine.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the [reference guide](http://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/docs/index.html#testing) can put you on the right path, if you've missed it?

Apart from the most common `expectNext`, which you must repeat for every single item in the sequence, you could use `expectNextCount` if you know the number of elements or `thenConsumeWhile` to skip elements based on a predicate,

Comment: I can't find `consumeNextWhile` in 3.0.6 or 3.0.7, I suppose it became `thenConsumeWhile`; since I don't want to make assertions on the sequence, I put a `.thenConsumeWhile(t->true)` after `thenAwait`, to skip every element and just check the duration, but the test runs indefinitely